# One XIB for multiple UITableViewCell subclasses

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib, custom-cell

I'm trying to use one XIB file for multiple types of custom UITableViewCell subclasses (same IBOutlets - same look - different methods and logic).

How can I do that?

Comment: Are u using single tablview?

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, the framework doesn't enforce a strict binding from an xib to its file owner. You can use the following code to load a nib:

```
NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EXCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
EXFirstCustomCell *firstCell = (EXFirstCustomCell*)[nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
firstCell.firstView = [firstCell.contentView viewWithTag:VIEW_TAG];
firstCell.button = [firstCell.contentView viewWithTag:BUTTON_TAG];
```

Based on your business logic, you can cast the result of `[nibContents objectAtIndex:0];` to suit your custom `UITableViewCell` class.

**Edit #1:**

Typecasting is generally a bad idea, since the `firstCell` will still be kind of class `UITableViewCell`. A good idea would be to create your own constructor, pass the `nibContents` as an argument and do your view assignments there.

**Edit #2**

I did a bit of experimentation and here is how I got this to work:

1. Create an independent xib view and design your cell there. It has to be a view. What you are doing here is you are defining how the `contentView` is going to be.
2. Load all the views from the xib.`NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EXCommonContentView" owner:nil options:nil];`
3. Create a constructor of your custom cell like so:

   ```
   -initWithNibContents:(NSArray*)nibContents {
       self = [super init]
       if(self) {
          self.contentView = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
          self.button = [self.contentView viewWithTag:BUTTON_TAG];
          self.view = [self.contentView viewWithTag:VIEW_TAG];
       }
    }
   ```